# Web Page for iPad: how to send data to server without PHP

Tags: ipad, web

I've developed a website that uses some PHP to write the client's user responses to a data file on my server.  I've realized that the iPad cannot run PHP sites, and I'm at a complete loss as to what a good alternative would be.  Javascript and HTML can't be used to write to a server, right?  Help?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I fixed it. The problem was that the iPad has problems with recognizing `.click`. I had to change it to `.bind("click tap touch", function....` instead. It's weird how it was still able to recognize the click events that did not initiate a form submission (that is, when I was still using `.click`, the button worked, except for when it had to submit a form).

Comment: You are confused. The iPad can interact with PHP sites just fine.

Comment: Javascript and html can be used to send to the server no problem.

Comment: I've updated my post to include some code.  It works on my computer, but not on the iPad.  Do I need to modify it for the iPad or am I not approaching this correctly?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to put the PHP scripts up on a web host (e.g. GoDaddy.com or BlueHost.com) and then navigate to the website from a web browser on your iPad. The PHP will run on the server and so it will work whether you access it on a PC or an iPad.

While your developing, you could also access the server running on your computer from your iPad by navigating to `http://<ip-address-of-your-computer>/myscript.php` from mobile Safari or Chrome.

[EDIT] - Please note that the second option will only work while your computer and iPad are both on the same network.